# Fusion charts Compatible with Mobile

Tags: fusioncharts

I am working with `FusioChartsXT` Trial Version.I am using this version for rendering charts in my cshtml pages.It is working fine .But showing a water mark as "Fusion Chart XT trial" below all charts.It is using single JavaScript file for rendering charts.. I am sharing code.

**In my Layout page**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>
```

****In My View Page****

```
var dashboardChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: chartType,
        renderAt: "chartContainer",
        width: chartWidth + 'px',
        height: "350",
        dataFormat: "xml",
        dataSource: $('#xmlDoc').val()
    ,
        "events": {

            "renderComplete": function (eventObj, argsObj) {
                loadResult();
            }

        }

    }
```

But our company already had fusion chart license. It is 3.2.2.2.It is using in old project which not required in mobile devices
How I can use to my current development?

Answer (score 0):

If You are using the Trial version the watermark is intended. And can not be removed by changing the code snippet you shared. If you have prior license files you need to replace your FusionCharts specific files with those old files and check whether they serve the purpose.

If not, you need to get in touch with FusionCharts, and buy / upgrade your license.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me in FusionCharts version  3.11.3 
add this css 
`[class*="creditgroup"]{
  display: none;
}`